# orientdb-client to communicate with orientdb server

Tags: node.js, module, soa, orientdb

I want to integrate a module into my app even a dependency for orientdb is it possible to integrate a orientdb-client in nodejs application?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/gabipetrovay/node-orientdb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at OrientJs, it is the official node js driver of OrientDb. (They adopted oriento and made it to orientjs)

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a Node.js driver for OrientDB look at: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs

Answer (score 1):

There are many OrientDB client in NPM. Check this out: 
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=orientdb